# Showing values inside Google GeoCharts

Tags: google-visualization

This is an example snippet from google.
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#fullhtml

**Data:**

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Country', 'Popularity'],
   ['South America', 600],
   ['Canada', 500],
   ['France', 600],
   ['Russia', 700],
   ['Australia', 600]
]);
var options = { displayMode: 'text' };
```

Here, `var options = { displayMode: 'text' }` display the country's name on the map (Without hovering over the country)

Is there any way to display the popularity data on the map?
I went through the documentation, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{role: 'annotation'}` to display the popularity value.

```
   function drawRegionsMap() {
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', {role: 'annotation'}],
      ['South America', '600'],
      ['Canada', '500'],
      ['France', '600'],
      ['Russia', '700'],
      ['Australia', '600']
   ]);
```

See the fiddle here [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/we4td8dy/5/)

[image]